# jQuery disable enable button style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to make a disable enable button style using jquery.

This is my [DEMO](http://codepen.io/shadowman86/pen/Buscf) page from Codepen

In my demo you can see there is a blue color submit button . When you write something in input filed then button is active.

I want to add when this button disable color is red. If the button not desable then button color change to blue.

I have create `.enableOnInput` and `.red` Css style for button.

```
.enableOnInput {
  width: 200px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    font: bold 10px/25px "Lucida Grande";
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,153,224,1);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    background-image: rgba(66,66,66,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #3db5ed 0%,#0099e0 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #3db5ed 0%,#0099e0 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #3db5ed 0%,#0099e0 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #3db5ed 0%,#0099e0 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #3db5ed 0%,#0099e0 100%);
}
.red {
    width: 20px;
    height: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-box-sizing: content-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: content-box;
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: rgba(255,255,255,1);
    font: bold 10px/25px "Lucida Grande";
    border: 1px solid rgba(0,153,224,1);
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-topright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomright: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius-bottomleft: 3px;
    border-top-left-radius: 3px;
    border-top-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 3px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 3px;
    background-image: rgba(66,66,66,1);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#c20202 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#c20202 100%);
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#c20202 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#c20202 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(top, #ff0000 0%,#c20202 100%);
}
```

This is my jquery for disable enable:

```
$(function(){
     $('#searchInput, #searchInput2').keyup(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == '') { //Check to see if there is any text entered
               //If there is no text within the input ten disable the button
               $('.enableOnInput').attr('disabled', 'true');
               $(".aa").show();
               $(".bb").hide();
          } else {
               //If there is text in the input, then enable the button
               $('.enableOnInput').attr('disabled', false);
               $(".aa").hide();
               $(".bb").show();
          }
     });
});
```

Comment: use `.prop()` instead of `.attr()`

Comment: @Anton i know this and i changed it. I want when button inactive button color is red . When button is active button color is blue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use `addClass/removeClass` methods:

```
 $('#searchInput, #searchInput2').keyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == '') { //Check to see if there is any text entered
           //If there is no text within the input ten disable the button
           $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true).addClass('red');
           $(".aa").show();
           $(".bb").hide();
      } else {
           //If there is text in the input, then enable the button
           $('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('red');
           $(".aa").hide();
           $(".bb").show();
      }
 }).keyup();
```

I also added trigged for keyup event to check initial state and set proper class.

**UPD**. Or as @Terry suggests in comments it's even better to change CSS selector to from `.red` to `.enableOnInput:disabled` and go with just `$('.enableOnInput').prop('disabled', true)`. Just note that this way it will not work in IE8 and below.

#### Demo: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CELut?editors=001

Comment: Even better: replace the CSS selector. Instead of using `.red`, OP can use `.enableOnInput[disabled]`: http://codepen.io/terrymun/pen/gdjhA

Comment: Also, props for using `.prop()` (no pun intended heh)

Answer (score 3):

Add this css rule:

```
input:disabled
{
  background-color: red;
  /*other style properties*/
}
```

Comment: Oh my god I could not think how to do it. Thank you  :)

Comment: This solution IMHO is the most relevant one — I''m actually in favour of this instead of toggling meaningless class names. `red` is a poor choice of CSS class — for example, what if you want to change the style of the disabled button such that it is no longer red? Then the class name betrays the appearance, and becomes contextually irrelevant.

Comment: give a way to minimalism))

Comment: @Terry Reasonable concern. The class name should be `.disabled` and styles declaration something like `.enableOnInput:disabled, .enableOnInput.disabled {}`.

Answer (score 1):

Add Class `red` to your button

```
<input type='submit' name='submit' id='submitBtn' class='enableOnInput red' disabled='disabled' />
```

add css rule

```
.red{
  background-color:red;
}
```

and your js

```
$(function(){
     $('#searchInput, #searchInput2').keyup(function(){
          if ($(this).val() == '') { //Check to see if there is any text entered
               //If there is no text within the input ten disable the button
               $('.enableOnInput').attr('disabled', 'true');
               $(".aa").show();
               $(".bb").hide();
            $('#submitBtn').addClass('red');
          } else {
               //If there is text in the input, then enable the button
               $('.enableOnInput').attr('disabled', false);
               $(".aa").hide();
               $(".bb").show();
            $('#submitBtn').removeClass('red');
          }
     });
});
```

[**Updated Link**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bpCFJ)